# Directory Listing at domain level (Apache)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf

I have a subdomain on an Apache 2.4 web server (an AWS EC2 host), with Indexes set - but it's not displaying the Index at the top level: only in subdirectories.  If there is no DirectoryIndex file (index.html) at the top level (http://stuff.example.com), it simply displays the Amazon Linux AMI Test Page.  If I have an index.html file at the top level, it's displayed normally.

I've tried to find documentation that Indexes are not displayed for domain pages, and couldn't.  Therefore I must be missing something in this basic configuration (httpd.conf):

```
<Directory "/data/stuff">
    AllowOverride Indexes AuthConfig
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName stuff.example.com
    DocumentRoot /data/stuff
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That “Amazon Linux AMI Test Page” is probably configured via `DirectoryIndex`, just with a different name than `index.htm(l)`, so that it only acts as a fallback if you don’t provide an index file yourself. Have you tried specifying `DirectoryIndex` yourself within the `Directory` directive? (Whether `DirectoryIndex` adds to an already existing configuration or overwrites it, depends on if it was already specified in the same context before.)

Comment: dear @CBroe - the "test page" isn't configured with `DirectoryIndex` but is coming from `/var/www/noindex/index.html` which is not a parameter anywhere in `httpd.conf` & apparently built into the default config: even if I specify `DirectoryIndex disabled` within the `Directory` directive it still yields that test page. I've also tried moving `Options Indexes` from the `VirtualHost` directive into the `Directory` directive (no change). Is there some specific phrasing you think I should try?

Comment: hold it; I see more configuration in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` & other files in `conf.d` - that's where the "test" (error) pages are defined. Will check if there are any directives in there that need to be overwritten....

Comment: and that, in fact, is the solution.  `welcome.conf` had `Options -Indexes` defined within `<LocationMatch "^/+$">` which the comments say is supposed to match the "root URL" - and, we have seen, also matches any naked subdomain. Commenting out that line restores the Directory Listing to the root URL of my subdomain. @CBroe if you would like to summarise the solution I will be happy to give you credit for it, otherwise I will do so... thanks /r

Comment: So the welcome page you saw was actually defined as the ErrorDocument for 403 Forbidden then? // Happy to let you write down what you found out yourself, as a [“self-answer”](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the AWS EC2 configuration of Apache 2.4 (at least), there is an additional config file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf`:

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
</LocationMatch>

<Directory /var/www/noindex>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /.noindex.html /var/www/noindex/index.html
```

Not only does this reveal the nature of the *Amazon Linux AMI Test Page*, it also explains why this page overrides the directory listing for the root URL of a subdomain: since it's matched by the regular expression in `LocationMatch`.

This code is meant to display something useful to the web site visitor if the web admin hasn't added an index page yet... yet it also has the side effect of suppressing directory listings for the root URL of any subdomain. One solution is to comment out, or remove, the `Options -Indexes` directive from `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf`.

Comment: ... and if I had to curtail "side effects" altogether, another solution would be to add an overriding `LocationMatch` directive in `httpd.conf`, matching the subdomain & containing `Options +Indexes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own DirectoryIndex and it will overrride default.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName stuff.example.com
    DocumentRoot /data/stuff
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
</VirtualHost>
```